# Using SQLConnection with files located in AppData folder

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, uwp

I downloaded a NuGet Package that uses `sqlite-net-pcl` and a few other libraries. It seems like all of them support `UWP`, because the Package Manager didn't throw an exception.

The problem I'm facing right now is the fact that my database file is in the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` directory, and it doesn't seem like `SQLite.SqlConnection` can access it via path that way:

```
Could not open database file: ms-appdata:///local/scrobbleCache.db (CannotOpen)
```

Is there any other way I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You may also need to install the extension `SQLite for Universal Windows Platform` in Visual Studio, and reference it in the project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you want to access SQLite DB.

```
var path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "scrobbleCache.db");  
using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))  
{  
    .....Do your Activity  
}
```

Comment: That's clever. I didn't think it'd actually work if I did it like that. Thank you!